# Rails 3 , Distinct count multiple having conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, group-by, fullcalendar

Some background.  I'm using Rails 3 for a carpooling application.  I'm using fullcalendar as the jquery calendar library.  It doesn't work *too* nicely when there are lots of events for a particular day.  So, what I want to do, is to have two "eventsources".  In one, I want to return all the events, grouped by date and category, that have a count less than some value.
For other, I want to return all the records which have a count *more* than the value.

Apologies if this isn't clear, some sample data might make it more obvious

Basic Record Structure:

```
|    id    |  date    |  category_id |
|    1     | 1-Aug    |       1      |
|    2     | 1-Aug    |       1      |
|    3     | 1-Aug    |       1      |
|    4     | 1-Aug    |       2      |
|    5     | 1-Aug    |       2      |
|    6     | 1-Aug    |       3      |
```

Assuming 3 is the magic count number (3 or higher should be grouped) I'd like one select to return

```
|    id    |  date    |  category_id |   count  |
|    1     | 1-Aug    |       1      |     3    |
```

(I don't actually care that the ID could be combined (with MYSQL) using a group_concat), in my use case it's not important - what I want to know is that on 1st August for category 1 there are 3 entries

The second select should return everything else

```
|    id    |  date    |  category_id |   count  |
|    4     | 1-Aug    |       2      |     2    |
|    5     | 1-Aug    |       2      |     2    |
|    6     | 1-Aug    |       3      |     1    |
```

I don't really need the count returned, but the point is that there are individual rows for every result which doesn't have a count >= 3.

Currently my SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT `pools`.*
FROM       `pools`
INNER JOIN `fields`    ON `fields`.`id`    = `pools`.`field_id` 
INNER JOIN `regions`   ON `regions`.`id`   = `fields`.`region_id` 
INNER JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `regions`.`country_id`
WHERE `regions`.`country_id` = 1
  AND `pools`.`confirmed`    = 1
  AND (leaving_date >= '2012-04-30 00:00:00')
  AND (leaving_date <= '2012-06-04 00:00:00')
GROUP BY field_id, leaving_date
HAVING   count(*) >= 3
ORDER BY leaving_date
```

I could iterate through the arrays returned - but I'd rather do it SQL side if it's possible.  Would also like to do it in the least number of database trips.. A general pointer would be really appreciated!

Comment: A general pointer would be to creat two scopes that return the data sets you want and use them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is useful for starting:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE grouped_rows AS
  SELECT `pools`.*
  FROM       `pools`
  INNER JOIN `fields`     ON `fields`.`id`    = `pools`.`field_id` 
  INNER JOIN `regions`    ON `regions`.`id`   = `fields`.`region_id` 
  INNER JOIN `countries`  ON `countries`.`id` = `regions`.`country_id`
  WHERE `regions`.`country_id` = 1
    AND `pools`.`confirmed`    = 1
    AND (leaving_date >= '2012-04-30 00:00:00')
    AND (leaving_date <= '2012-06-04 00:00:00')
  GROUP BY field_id, leaving_date;
  HAVING   count(*) >= 3;


SELECT `pools`.*
FROM       `pools`
INNER JOIN `fields`     ON `fields`.`id`    = `pools`.`field_id` 
INNER JOIN `regions`    ON `regions`.`id`   = `fields`.`region_id` 
INNER JOIN `countries`  ON `countries`.`id` = `regions`.`country_id`
LEFT  JOIN grouped_rows ON grouped_rows.field_id     = pools.field_id
                       AND grouped_rows.leaving_date = pools.leaving_date
WHERE `regions`.`country_id` = 1
  AND `pools`.`confirmed`    = 1
  AND (leaving_date >= '2012-04-30 00:00:00')
  AND (leaving_date <= '2012-06-04 00:00:00')
  AND grouped_rows.some_not_null_field IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM grouped_rows

ORDER BY leaving_date;


DROP TEMPORARY TABLE grouped_rows;
```

I don't know if you can issue all three statements and get the results of the `UNION` in one roundtrip.
Maybe you could embed the temptable's select into both halves of the `UNION`, but it may give some more work to the MySQL server (or not).

**Update:**

I found a one-query solution that you can use. This is just the basic skeleton structure, but I think you can convert your query according to it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f67e3/18

```
SELECT
  IF( grouped.gcat, NULL, item.id ) AS out_id
 ,item.cat AS out_cat
 ,COALESCE( grouped.gcount, 1 ) out_count

FROM item

LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT   count(*) AS gcount, cat AS gcat
  FROM     item
  GROUP BY gcat
  HAVING   count(*) >= 3
) AS grouped
  ON item.cat = grouped.gcat

GROUP BY out_id
```

Comment: Right - so there is no way to do it in the on SQL call?  And certainly not nicely in Rails?  Damn!  Will mark it as correct so (and sorry for the delay!)